# Unclosed div makes range slider work, but breaks site

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider-range">

    </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

This is for a jQuery UI range slider. The empty div makes the handles and slider it'self work but also breaks the entire website.

Here is a preview of the functioning slider:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kCiwl

Not sure what to replace it with so it still function correctly. Thoughts?

Comment: What is the problem to **close** this `<div>` with `</div>`?

Comment: It makes the slider unfunction-able. Try it out in the codepen.

Comment: Can't replicate your issue. Closing the `<div>` properly works for me: http://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/mlutr

Comment: **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/efbmd**. I removed that whole empty `div` in between and it still works fine for me

Comment: *design advice*: I would make the slider horizontal is at all possible